# locus of end of latus rectum.

Tags: geometry

Let (0, a)bethe focus and 2x-y-1=0 be the directrix of a parabola. Then we have to prove that the locus of end of the latus rectum is

3x+y+1=0

And

7x-y-1=0

I tried .

As   (x)$^2$-(y-a)$^2$ =(2x-y-1)$^2$/(5)

This is the equation of ellipse , but how to proceed

Comment: "...of end of the latus rectum..."?? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As the "latus rectum of a conic section is the chord through a focus parallel to the conic section directrix (Coxeter 1969)", the equation of the latus rectum will be $$2x-y-c=0\iff c=2x-y=-a\iff 2x-y+a=0$$

Find the two intersections of the latus rectum with the parabola.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is easy to compute the distance between focus and directrix as $FH=(1+a)/\sqrt5$.
If $A$ is one of the endpoints of the latus rectum, the similitude between triangles $FHK$ and $ACF$ gives $CA=(1+a)/5$ and $CF=2CA$ (remember that $AF=FH$). From that it is easy to find the coordinates of $A$, and a similar reasoning can be made for point $B$.

[image]